# Question about multiplets of 6d $\mathcal{N}=(1,0)$ SUSY

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, representation-theory, superconformality

In [Strathdeee's "Extended Poincare Supersymmetry"](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217751X87000120), the first entry on page 16 lists the massless multiplets of 6d $\mathcal{N} = (1,0)$ supersymmetry as

- $2^2 = (2,1; 1) \oplus (1,1; 2)$. This is the half-hyper (matter) multiplet.
- $(2,1;1) \otimes 2^2 = (3, 1;1) \oplus (1,1; 1) \oplus (2,1; 2)$. This is the tensor multiplet.
- $(1,2;2) \otimes 2^2 = (2,2;1) \oplus (1,2;2)$. This is the vector (Yang-Mills) multiplet.
- $(2,3;1) \otimes 2^2 = (3,3;1) \oplus (1,3;1) \oplus (2,3;2)$. This is the gravity multiplet.

where the entries specify representations of the little group $SO(4) \simeq SU(2) \times SU(2)$ and the R-symmetry group $USp(2) \simeq SU(2)$.

But there's also another entry:

- $(1,2;3) \otimes 2^2 = (2,2; 3) \oplus (1,2;2) \oplus (1,2;4)$

which consists of (1) a vector transforming in the adjoint of the R-symmetry, (2) a Weyl spinor transforming in the doublet of R-symmetry, and (3) another Weyl soinor transforming in the **4**-dimensional representation of the R-symmetry group.

**What is this fifth multiplet?** Is there some reason why it doesn't feature in discussions about 6d $\mathcal{N} = (1,0)$ theories, even in papers from the 90s by Seiberg and others?

Comment: Maybe it is a multiplet that is specific to theories with gravity, and therefore it is not present in the (non-gravitational) analysis of Seiberg and others ?

Comment: What kind of multiplet would that be? The gravity multiplet includes a gravitino.

Comment: It would be a 3-form multiplet. However I can't find any precise reference about it.

Comment: The issue is likely that the vector is charged under the R-symmetry.

Comment: Yes, it is charged...but does that preclude it from discussion/consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Free equations of motion for all D = 6 supermultiplets](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(88)90311-2), page 224:

> For example $$(1,2;3) \otimes 2^2 = (2,2; 3) \oplus (1,2; 2) \oplus 
>  (1,2; 4)$$ can be interpreted as an $USp(2)$ $(2,0)$-Yang-Mills multiplet,
>    its component field strengths being $(\lambda_a^{A\alpha}, 
>  F^{A\beta}_{\alpha})$ where A is an $USp(2)$ adjoint index.   Notice
>    also that any  multiplet with extended supersymmetry can be thought of
>    as being composed of  simple (i.e. $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$) multiplets, with appropriate assignments to extended  $USp(N)$ irreps.